# Exchange 2010 Transition: redirect OWA

Tags: exchange-2010

Does the -Exchange2003Url need to resolve to a *different* public IP address than the 'standard' mail owa address. For example, I have mail.domain.com and legacy.domain.com pointing to the same public ip address (xxx.xxx.xxx.163).

Right now the public mail address is pointing to our Exchange 2003 server. Everything is working fine - I have only moved one test users to Exch 2010. When I point mail.domain.com to the Exch 2010 server, only the mailbox on the 2010 server can be accessed. It tries to redirect to legacy.domain.com and I get 404 file or directory not found.

Comment: Are you connecting over HTTP or HTTPS? It sounds like you're using HTTPS, and since you only have one public IP, are forwarding the port to only one Exchange server. This would make requests for `https://mail.domain.com` and `https://legacy.domain.com` both be passed to the same server, and 2003 URLs are not being found because you're hitting the 2010 server.

This kind of a migration is going to be very hard if you only have one public IP. Do you have more IPs available?

Comment: We tried mucking around with an alternate port but it was more trouble than it was worth.  We ended up getting a secondary (cheap) ADSL connection with one static IP and planned on keeping it for a month or two but ended up leaving it up and running for failover; at ~$60/month, it was a no-brainer.

Comment: Get a 2nd static IP and do it right.

Comment: This makes sense - I have another IP address thats propagating as I speak. I thought I looked over quite a bit of transition info and this wasn't clear. However, it makes sense that theres really no other way for it to work.

Comment: Can your firewall or reverse proxy device do different redirction based on virtual directory? Can it redirect `https://publicip/owa` and `https://publicip/ecp` to the E2010 CAS and `https://publicip/exchange` (and the other virtual directories) to the E2003 box?

Comment: AFAIK my sonicwall NSA2400 cannot redirect like that (according to sonicwall support). I had a public IP address that I used to forward.